# Should I set sunshade posts in concrete or on piers?

Tags: concrete, construction, post

I have a concrete pad that is 12’x22’ that is standard 4” thick that we use for an outside dining area. We would like to add a sunshade to cover 90% of the concrete. The height of the sunshade will be between 12’ and 9’ with diagonally opposite corners being one height and the other corners being lower to address rain runoff. I have purchased 6”x6” pressure treated posts already (recommended because I was told that 4”x4” posts would bend). There will be virtually no vertical stress on these posts, only horizontal stress since we are not building a structure.

My question is how to install the posts? From what I can tell I have three options:

1. Dig a hole and place the posts in concrete( how deep, how wide of a hole)
2. Drill holes in concrete pad and mount a bracket that would hold post. What type of bracket? Since I want to cover most of the pad I would need to place the posts as close to the edge of the pad as possible and I’m concerned about cracking or breaking the concrete from the stress of the wind.
3. Dig hole and pour concrete pier outside of the area of the pad to mount bracket to. What should the dimensions be for the pier and what type of bracket should I use?

Answer (score 2):

No bracket will hold a post upright. That's a common misunderstanding. You'd need robustly engineered heavy-gauge steel bracing.

Either your posts need to be well anchored below frost line (and at least 1/3 post height), or your structure needs to be independently rigid, such as with "knee bracing" (diagonals at corners). See many discussions here and elsewhere on pergolas, decks, and fences. Principles overlap quite a bit.

- [How can I reduce flex/sway in my pergola?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/197630/how-can-i-reduce-flex-sway-in-my-pergola)
- [Is it normal for a freestanding pergola to wobble a little bit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/193221/is-it-normal-for-a-freestanding-pergola-to-wobble-a-little-bit)
- [Attaching Pergola posts to lumber on ground](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/219638/attaching-pergola-posts-to-lumber-on-ground)
- [How do I improve Pergola Stability?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/how-do-i-improve-pergola-stability)
- [How deep do I need to make the post footings for a residential deck in Northern Michigan?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222274/how-deep-do-i-need-to-make-the-post-footings-for-a-residential-deck-in-northern)
- [What is a reasonable depth and diameter for postholes dug in clay soil to support an 8' fence?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/137885/what-is-a-reasonable-depth-and-diameter-for-postholes-dug-in-clay-soil-to-suppor)